# Can a path param have a path alias as input in falcon REST framework?

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, falconframework

I have an GET Rest endpoint say it as /test/{id}. Currently i am passing id and getting the response as expected.
Now i would like that GET endpoint /test/{id} to consume something different value along with id.
The different value would be path alias like a/b/c.

so if request is like /test/a/b/c then everything apart from /test i.e. /a/b/c should be treated as single value. How can i achieve that in Falcon.

I tried using router_options converter in falcon.

```
import falcon
import json
from falcon.routing import BaseConverter
from waitress import serve


class ObjectRequest:
    def on_get(self, req, resp):
        print(req)
        resp.status = falcon.HTTP_200
        resp.body = json.dumps({'message': 'Hello World!'})


class AppNameConverter(BaseConverter):

    def convert(self, value):
        return value


api = falcon.API()
api.router_options.converters.update({
    'app_name': AppNameConverter
})
api.add_route('/test/{app:app_name}', ObjectRequest())
serve(app=api, host='127.0.0.1', port=8000)
```